# Adding style to Angular2 Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript

Hi I am new to Angular2/Typescript and I am trying to style a map that I added to my Angular2 project by using the [Angular2 Google Maps Components](https://angular-maps.com/) but I can´t figure out how to use its not yet documented [MapTypeStyle Interface](https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/index/MapTypeStyle-interface.html). How do I use it in my module and the html? The map module works but I don´t get the styles applied. Any help appreciated.

The according [Google MapsTypeStyle Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle)

html:

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

module (excerpt)

```
export class GmapComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string = 'Current Location';
  lat: number = 50.937531;
  lng: number = 6.960278600000038;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the styles you're trying to apply? The [getting started guide](https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html) just says to use `styleUrls: ['app.component.css']` in the component declaration. Your example doesn't provide detail about the style you're trying to apply.

Comment: in the components css I only add styles to the component itself, like width and height of the map. What I would like to achieve ist to apply the JASON formatted style for example form https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ and from my undestanding this needs to be added via the api(?)

Answer (score 8):

The docs aren't very useful, so I had to dig into the code for the component.

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [styles]="styles">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

Just adding `styles` should work, where `styles` is of the type `MapTypeStyle[]` which is [declared here](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/blob/500dce0d41f23dab9c78b8fa18674ed92e164072/src/core/services/google-maps-types.ts#L152).

Try defining `styles` as something like:

```
let styles = [{
  "featureType": "water",
  "stylers": [{
      "color": "#ff0000"
    }]
}];
```

That *should* make your water red, but I haven't tested this myself yet, I'm just basing it off the code.

Comment: hello i want change label test color how it posible  ?

Answer (score 6):

## This is working for me. ☺ :-p

```
<sebm-google-map *ngIf="map" [latitude]="placeLat" [longitude]="placeLng" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom" [disableDefaultUI]="true" [styles]='[
            {
                elementType : "labels.icon",
                stylers : [{
                  visibility : "off"
                }]
            }]'>
```

Comment: Please add some information what you changed, what the errors were and how you solved it. Simply posting the fixed code doesnt help anyone cause the same errors will be made again...

Comment: when i use [styles]="styles" and pass json data in variable 'styles', it doesn't work,then i have passed the data in json directly.

Answer (score 1):

My final working solution. But I still don´t understand where and how MapTypeStyle Interface is used.

html adding `[styles]="customStyle"`

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [styles]="customStyle" >
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" ></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

component (excerpt) adding `public customStyle = [{ "JSON style declaration goes here" }]`

```
export class GmapComponent implements OnInit {

  public customStyle = [
    {
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "hue": "#ff4400"
        },
        {
          "saturation": -100
        },
        {
          "lightness": -4
        },
        {
          "gamma": 0.72
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "labels.icon"
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "hue": "#0077ff"
        },
        {
          "gamma": 3.1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "hue": "#00ccff"
        },
        {
          "gamma": 0.44
        },
        {
          "saturation": -33
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "hue": "#44ff00"
        },
        {
          "saturation": -23
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "hue": "#007fff"
        },
        {
          "gamma": 0.77
        },
        {
          "saturation": 65
        },
        {
          "lightness": 99
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "gamma": 0.11
        },
        {
          "weight": 5.6
        },
        {
          "saturation": 99
        },
        {
          "hue": "#0091ff"
        },
        {
          "lightness": -86
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.line",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "lightness": -48
        },
        {
          "hue": "#ff5e00"
        },
        {
          "gamma": 1.2
        },
        {
          "saturation": -23
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "saturation": -64
        },
        {
          "hue": "#ff9100"
        },
        {
          "lightness": 16
        },
        {
          "gamma": 0.47
        },
        {
          "weight": 2.7
        }
      ]
    }
  ];



  title: string = 'Current Location';
  lat: number = 50.937531;
  lng: number = 6.960278600000038;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: The custom style is of the `MapTypeStyle` type. At the top of your document if you add `import { MapTypeStyle } from 'angular2-google-maps;` you can then change the line `public customStyle = [` to `public customStyle: MapTypeStyle = [`, which ensures the custom style is of the correct type. It's not essential though, since it's working for you.